# What's the best way to switch from Stock Android OS to Cyanogenmod on Galaxy S3?

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-3, rooting, backup

I would like to switch my Stock Android OS to Cyanogenmod with the least trouble possible on my Samsung Galaxy S3.

So basically I would like to keep:

- My data (files, contacts, sms)
- My apps
- My apps data (progress of games)

Is this even possible?

What is the best approach to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your device is not yet rooted, an alternative to [Alex's suggestion](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/56223/16575) of *Titanium Backup* (which I'd second otherwise) would be to use `adb backup` (creating a backup file for each app separately is important here, as `adb restore` just works per backup file, not per app), or one of its frontends. There's also the possibility to do that directly on the device, using e.g. [Helium Backup](http://www.appbrain.com/app/helium-app-sync-and-backup/com.koushikdutta.backup).

Please also take a look at the [backup](/questions/tagged/backup) [tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/backup/info) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [Titaniun Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup&hl=en), thought it's not sure that everything will work as expected. Apps are the most problematic.

Some apps and games now store their data on Google's servers, though I don't think there are many that do that yet.

Comment: Titanium Backup is *the* gold standard for backup apps. However... a note: You need to be rooted in order to get Titanium Backup. For many phones, gaining root for the first time involves a factory reset. Therefore this may not be the best option.